# What is the expected number of dice one needs to roll to get 1,2,3,4,5,6 in order?

Tags: probability, statistics, dice

If I have a fair die and throw it until I get a run of 1,2,3,4,5,6 in order, how many times on average must I throw the dice?

Comment: Considering the corresponding transition matrix, we obtain that the average trial you need to get a run of 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 is 46656.

Comment: There are $6^6 = 46656$ permutations of the results. The run you want to obtain is unique, so it has the probability $\frac{1}{46656}$. Therefore, the expected number of times you have to throw the dice is $46656$.

Comment: @rubik: It doesn't work like that. You could also get a run of $1,2,3,4,5,6$ starting at the second dice roll. After $N$ throws you have $N - 5$ runs of length $6$, and you want one of them to be this specific one.

Comment: @rubik, the probability should be greater than 1/46656, since dice is thrown continuously.

Comment: @rubik: If you were looking for 1,1,1,1,1,1 then you would get a different (larger) answer.

Comment: @sos440: Did you solve the question with the method you indicate? (Just curious.)

Comment: @DidierPiau: Of course... though I borrowed the power of Mathematica. Let $$\Omega = \{ 0, 1, 12, 123, 1234, 12345, 123456 \}$$ be the sample space of possible intermediate states, and let $A$ be the corresponding matrix. Then for the initial state $\mathrm{x}_0 = (1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)$, we can calculate the expected trial from $$(A + 2A^2 + 3A^3 + \cdots)\mathrm{x}_0 = A (I - A)^{-2} \mathrm{x}_0.$$ But inverting a $7\times 7$ matrix is somewhat demanding, so I used Mathematica for this step.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's write

- $a = $ expected throws to succeed with no useful throws recently
- $b = $ expected throws to succeed with 1 recently
- $c = $ expected throws to succeed with 1,2 recently
- $d = $ expected throws to succeed with 1,2,3 recently
- $e = $ expected throws to succeed with 1,2,3,4 recently
- $f = $ expected throws to succeed with 1,2,3,4,5 recently
- $g = $ expected throws to succeed with 1,2,3,4,5,6 recently

then

- $g = 0$
- $f = 1 + \frac16 g + \frac16 b + \frac46 a$
- $e = 1 + \frac16 f + \frac16 b + \frac46 a$
- $d = 1 + \frac16 e + \frac16 b + \frac46 a$
- $c = 1 + \frac16 d + \frac16 b + \frac46 a$
- $b = 1 + \frac16 c + \frac16 b + \frac46 a$
- $a = 1 + \frac16 b + \frac56 a$

so

- $a = 6 + b$
- $\frac16 b + \frac46 a = 4 + \frac56 b $
- $b = 30 + c$
- $\frac16 b + \frac46 a = 29 + \frac56 c $
- $c = 180 + d$
- $\frac16 b + \frac46 a = 179 + \frac56 d $
- $d = 1080 + e$
- $\frac16 b + \frac46 a = 1079 + \frac56 e $
- $e = 6480 + f$
- $\frac16 b + \frac46 a = 6479  + \frac56 f $
- $f = 38880 + g$

i.e.

- $a = 6 + 30 + 180 + 1080 + 6480 + 38880 + 0 = 46656$

So the answer is $46656$.

This is $6^6$ so the "obvious solution" turns out to be correct and there is probably a quicker way.

Comment: why $f = 1 + \frac16 g + \frac16 b + \frac46 a$ ?

Comment: Could you explain explicitly where the formulae for a-g come from?

Comment: @quartz: If you are at a position ending `12345` then you must throw the die, hence the $1$.  You have a $\frac16$ chance of a `6` so you add a sixth of $g$, a $\frac16$ chance of a `1` so you add a sixth of $b$,and a $\frac46$ chance of a `2`,`3`,`4` or `5` so you add a sixth of $a$. Hence the equation.

Comment: @j coe:  See my response to @quartz. The others are similar.  For $g$, you have finished so $g=0$.

Comment: Note that for this argument to work, we need to already know that the expectations involved are all finite.

Comment: Is it really the "obvious solution"? After 46656 throws you've generated 46651 sequences of 6 throws; $6^6+5$ seems more obvious.

Comment: @Peter: There are other questions to which it is not the correct solution, but it was the solution put forward in the comments to the question at the time I gave the answer.

Comment: There is a quicker way using a version of Conway's algorithm looking for matching patterns at the beginning and end. So for example $666666$ has $6,66,666,6666,66666,666666$ matching so the expectation is $6^1+6^2+6^3+6^4+6^5+6^6$, while $123321$ has $1,123321$ matching so the expectation is $6^1+6^6$, and $565656$ has $56,5656,565656$ matching so the matching so the expectation is $6^2+6^4+6^6$.  Here $123456$ only matches itself so the expectation is $6^6$

Answer (score 5):

For each $k\geqslant6$, call $x_k$ the six last positions occupied at time $k$. Introduce $t_0=0$ and, for each $n\geqslant1$, $t_n$ the $n$th time when the word `123456` got completed, that is, $t_n$ denotes the $n$th visit to `123456` of the process $(x_k)_{k\geqslant6}$. The question asks for $\mathrm E(t_1)$.

Note that the sequence $(t_{n+1}-t_{n})_{n\geqslant0}$ is i.i.d. and distributed like $t_1$. This step uses the fact that after a completion of `123456` one must start to build a new occurrence entirely anew, that is, that no nontrivial suffix of `123456` is also a prefix of `123456`. (Otherwise, $(t_{n+1}-t_{n})_{n\geqslant1}$ would be i.i.d. but with a different distribution than $t_1$, more precisely, the distribution of $t_{n+1}-t_n$ for every $n\geqslant1$ would be strictly dominated by the distribution of $t_1$, in particular, for every $n\geqslant1$, one would have $\mathrm E(t_1)\gt\mathrm E(t_{n+1}-t_n)$. In the present case, $\mathrm E(t_1)=\mathrm E(t_{n+1}-t_n)$.)

The process $(x_k)_k$ performs a random walk on the regular directed graph with $N=6^6$ vertices where every vertex `1u` is linked to the six vertices `u1`, `u2`, ..., to `u6`, for every given 5-letters word `u`. The out-degree and the in-degree of every vertex being all equal to 6, the stationary distribution of the Markov chain is uniform, in particular the weight of `123456` is $w=1/N$.

By the law of large numbers for ergodic Markov chains, the asymptotic proportion of time spent at `123456` is almost surely $w$, that is, $t_n=(n/w)+o(n)$ almost surely. By the law of large numbers for i.i.d. sequences, $t_n=n\mathrm E(t_1)+o(n)$ almost surely.

Comparing these two expressions, one gets $\mathrm E(t_1)=1/w=N=6^6=46656$.